# Pointing a domain name to a webpage

Tags: dns, web-hosting, cname

I'm hosting a [project page on github](https://pages.github.com/) at `somedude.github.io/thingeroo` and I own the `thingeroo.com` domain name (through 1&1.com).

I know that I can set up a CNAME to point from `thingeroo.com` to `somedude.github.io`, but can I somehow point to `somedude.github.io/thingeroo`? If I can’t do this through CNAME entries—and it seems that this is the case—can I do it through some other means?

Answer (score 2):

If you want `thingeroo.com` to point to `somedude.github.io/thingeroo` then this would require github, in this case, to cooperate by acting as a proxy. Fortunately github actually does this! All you have to do is:

1. Specify an A Record for `thingeroo.com` that points to the appropriate github server (`192.30.252.154` or `192.30.252.153`)
2. Add a CNAME file in your github repo's gh-pages branch with the contents `thingeroo.com`. This latter step is what allows github to know where to send the requests.

More details [on this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9082499/custom-domain-for-github-project-pages/22374542#22374542).

Answer (score 1):

CNAME records don't have anything to do with redirecting HTTP requests.  They're for host names.  You can't use a CNAME record for this purpose.

Fortunately, almost all domain registrars provide a service that will allow you to redirect requests to your domain to somewhere else.  They do this by setting your DNS A records to their web servers where a lightweight application receives the request, inspects the Host header, and then redirects the browser to a URL elsewhere.

You can usually find a setting for this on your registrar's control panel, around the same place you find parking pages.

Comment: This topic is foreign to me so I'm having trouble figuring out what to google to get the answers I want. Any tips?

Comment: Oh... and just to be sure. I don't actually want to do and HTTP redirect. I want users to visit thingeroo.com and see my blog. I don't want them to visit thingeroo.com and be redirected to somedude.github.io/thingeroo.

Comment: @JohnBerryman That isn't directly possible.  That would require GitHub to support such functionality.  The only thing you could do would be to set up a proxy server that rewrites all of the URLs and links in markup.

Comment: You are correct, but also github does server as a proxy - so it works out. I'll post another answer.

Comment: @JohnBerryman I realize you figured out GitHub can handle this, but most hosting services offer basic URL redirection services from their control panel in which you can assign a redirect URL for a domain name and that URL can be whatever you want. CNAME and A name records only have to do with the host of the URL, `somedude.github.io`. Anthging to the right of the hostname is handled by a web server via HTTP processes.